# Will any issues be generated in PHP functions when migrated from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, database-migration

As our client upgraded the cpanel version, they are asked to upgrade MySQL version also.We have coded the program in PHP Version 5.3.2 and MySQL - 5.1.73 .Thus if we upgrade the MySQL to 5.5 will it generate any issues to the PHP function codes.

Comment: I think there is no issue when it comes to mysql version upgrade.

Comment: An error could only occur in case when the php driver for mysql does not support a -lets say - new protocol, which mysql relies on. This is not the case, so you should not get any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will not create any issues if you upgrade our mysql version, But I will suggest you please discuss this with your developer, If they have setup any code and that code syntax is working only with mysql 5.1

Comment: Thank you..currently our MySQL storage engine is Myisam and MySQL 5.5 versions default storage engine is INNODB.Our database is very huge so will any issues occur when migrated.